# How to emulate 'cp --update' behavior on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell

The [GNU/Linux version of `cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) has a nice `--update` flag:

> **-u, --update**
>   copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

The [Mac OS X version of `cp`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) lacks this flag.

What is the best way to get the behavior of `cp --update` by using built-in system command line programs?  I want to avoid installing any extra tools (including the GNU version of `cp`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`rsync`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) has an `-u`/`--update` option that works just like GNU `cp`:

```
$ rsync -u src dest
```

Answer (score 4):

Also look at rsync's other options, which are probably what you actually want:

```
    -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
    -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links
    -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
        --executability         preserve executability
    -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
    -g, --group                 preserve group
        --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials              preserve special files
    -D                          same as --devices --specials
    -t, --times                 preserve times

    -a, --archive
          This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion 
          and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a  notable  omission).   The
          only exception to the above equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which 
          case -r  is not implied.

          Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding multiply-linked files is
          expensive.  You must separately specify -H.
```